# Do I need a pulley extractor to replace the small drive belt (225-5M) for SnowJoe SJ625E?

Tags: blower, snow, pulleys

First let me say that I called the SnowJoe technical support and they could not help.

I am trying to replace the belt that goes around the pulley marked with a red arrow in the below diagram (from their [manual](https://files.snowjoe.com/product-manuals/SJ625EMANUAL_ENG11082017-V1.pdf)). The problem is that the flanged pulley has a shoulder that forces you to fully install the belt around it before trying to install it around the driver pulley. (see the second picture for terminology)

[image]

**This is for terminology reference, I hope I am using the right names for these parts, I am not a mechanic**

[image]

**Here is what it looks like with no belt**

[image]

**And here is how close I can get without forcing it**

[image]

To me it seems that the only way to put this back is to use a pulley extractor. Is there a better way?

Comment: It does not seems to have tension adjustment, or I do not see it, it is strange not to have tension adjustment

Comment: yes it a POS assembly and the belt is very rigid this method does not work here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Cd8Np26_qU&ab_channel=WrenchTurner

Comment: I can not see well, but is there a slot going from smaller to the larger

Comment: Youtube videos make stuff look easy.  What they don't show is you probably need more than two hands.  Being a weight lifter helps.  Even using a gear puller, you still have the problem of getting the gear back on and will need to lever it back in place.

Comment: My expectation would be that the belt fits tight around the two pulleys (driver and flange pulley) and I should be able to push/hammer it it back into position using a piece of wood to absorb the hit (the pulley seem to be made of aluminum

Comment: It is nice to dream.  That belt will hold the pulley at angle at best when trying to put it back on

Comment: @Ruskes - Probably don't need a tensioner for a cogged belt like that, since it doesn't rely on belt-to-pulley friction for operation.

Comment: I think I'm seeing a hex socket in the hub of the larger pulley...? Plus the C clip holding the smaller one. I suspect that both should come off without a gear puller unless they're rusted in place

Comment: they are made of aluminum . the flange pulley had a hex nut that came out easy but the pulley did not move. It might be a better idea to try to extract the driver pulley although that is mounted on the motor so putting it back might affect the rotor if hammered. I think the C clamp is there just in case. You do not want that pulley to freely spin by itself when the motor is started so there must be a way to hold it in  position to avoid this

Comment: Heating the belt will make it larger and more stretchy, might be enough to make the difference.  A hot air gun or hair dryer should work. Likewise, get the metal parts cold first, keeping it outside overnight for example, that will make them smaller. Fun fact: the wing hinge pin on an F-14 tomcat needs soaked in liquid nitrogen before inserting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after some wresting with this thing I managed to fix it. Here is how you do it:

The flanged pulley is key here, that one must be removed and then the belt can be installed. Depending on your luck it might come out easy or not. The third picture shows a nut that you need to remove, be careful with that you need to unscrew it as you would normally tighten it (it is designed to tighten itself as the shaft is spinning). After removing that nut you should be able to pull the flange out, it it is not coming off then use two prybars and push it upward evenly and at the same time. If it is still not moving do not force it as the piece is made of aluminum allow and it might crack (I came across reports/reviews saying that they tried to force the belt in as suggested in some of the below answers and the flanged pulley cracked). So to safely do that you need to remove the blue plastic cover so you can have free access to the pulley from all sides. They you can use a pulley remover as shown in the picture. In my case this as not needed as after having complete access to the pulley I was able to find better angles from my pry bars and I was able to pry it out a little. The pulley remover must have thin tips as it needs to get under the flange and there is not a lot or room there (less than 1/4" and the pulley remover might not get the right angle in order to get the grip there).
As you can see in the below pictures I was able to replace the belt easily after that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Page 13 and 14 clearly show how to do it

[manual](https://files.snowjoe.com/product-manuals/SJ625EMANUAL_ENG11082017-V1.pdf)

To remove or install the belt, you would put it over the drive pulley first, then partially (as much you can) over the auger pulley, then start turning the auger (while pushing the belt down to make the belt slip over it.

No tools neded

[image: belt]

Use your right hand to press the belt with the ribbed side down. While holding the belt down with your right hand, use your left hand to turn the auger forward so that the auger pulley rotates in a clockwise direction. The belt will be gradually pushed down onto the pulley. When the belt is seated on the pulley, adjust it so that the ribs of the belt match the grooves on the pulley. (Fig. 29).

[image: belt]

Wrench hold

[image: wrench]

Comment: Can you see the red arrow in my diagram ? There is a short belt there . You are looking at the wrong belt

Comment: @MiniMe same method applies,

Comment: @MiniMe What I was showing you is for the smaller belt, the larger one is called Pulley, the smaller is called Auger -pulley. Same method (slip over) applies to both to install the belt. Fig 31 and 32

Comment: That is the usual approach, yes. And yes, stretching the belt into position this way can sometimes take a significant amount of force. Putting a long-handled wrench on the bolt holding the pulley may give you a better lever arm while the belt stretches into place

Comment: tried with a long screw driver and used the end of the shaft that protrudes out of the driver pulley as leverage point and I had no luck. It requires a lot of force to stretch that belt enough to get it in place and you may damage it that way

Comment: @Ruskes that pulley has two levels. One that represents the driver for the bigger pulley ..they are mixing the terms ... the manual is a POS

Comment: @MiniMe see my updated answer/picture

Comment: @MiniMe I know it has two belts, take look at the smallest cog, it has a cut in it so you can use a wrench to assist you. you put first the belt on the small then force it over the bigger one by turning with wrench assistance,

Comment: You can not get even close to putting the belt on the edge of the flanged pulley because that has a shoulder that is larger in diameter than the pulley ...that is why you can't see it

Answer (score 1):

Possible (can't see anything that's "for certain" that the parts might have a less-obvious tensioning method, like an eccentric mount, where something can be loosened to allow a collar around the shaft to rotate, and the hole for the shaft is off-center in that part, so the distance changes.

However, if you want to pull the small cogged pulley, the C-clip implies that it will probably come off without requiring a puller once you remove the C-clip.

Before you go there:

Rather than the ham-fisted approach shown in your you-tube clip, might try a nail or rod somewhat smaller than your pulley teeth engaged at one side of the pulley and belt inside the belt, outside the pulley, coming "straight up" from your picture) and rotating the assembly to pull that around the small pulley while pushing down on the belt to work it onto the pulley. Perhaps it's too tight to work, but more likely to than clumsy screwdriver-ing.

Comment: I considered that but (using a nail) but a nail that thin will bent before bringing the belt into the desired position.

Comment: You considered it; but did you **actually try** it? That's a healthy cog size, and the nail doesn't need to end the day as straight as it started if it will let you get the edge of the belt on the pulley, at which point you keep rotating and pushing (without the nail in there.)

Comment: I just did. There is no way you can use a nail or a thin rod for this. I tried to use a screw driver and that gets the belt on the driver pulley for a little bit there is now way to rotate or to push it down, it springs back imediately